# how do i convert a array of values returned from a query to comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a result set that is being returned using this code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "ID ".$row['v2id'];

}
```

this returns ID 2ID 3ID 4ID 8

how would i convert this to comma separated values and then store them in a variable?

so if i echoed out the variable, the final output would should look like 2, 3, 4, 8

Comment: Can the values themselves contain commas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

store all the values in an array, then join them using ", " as the glue

```
$values = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $values[] = $row['v2id'];
}

echo join(", ", $values);
```

Comment: how would i then use these values in a query like: SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id IN (value, value, value);

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id IN (' . join(',', $values). ')'`. Make sure that $values is not an empty array otherwise you'll end up with a syntax error in your sql.

Comment: This will work in this case since you only appear to be storing numbers, but it should be noted that CSV files are more complex than just a list of values concatenated with commas. If `$values` were to contain any items with a comma in it the outputted string would not be correctly parsed if trying to convert it back into an array.  If you are just joining them for display to humans this will work fine but if you want it to be machine readable you'll have to do more than just `join`ing them.

Comment: @Salman A i have tried to use he query suggested however this returns no results how do i check that the $ values is not an empty array? i have used the following code: `$resultone = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_id IN (' . join(',', $values). ')"); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $resultone )) { echo "name ".$row['video_name']; }`

Comment: @james: do you get a mysql error? Try adding `if($resultone === false) die(mysql_error());` after the line where you call mysql_query. BTW you can check `if (count($values) > 0)`. Or you can initialize $values as `$values = array(-1)`. `-1` is an arbitrary value that is not supposed to be present in your video_id column (e.g. if it is an auto_increment column you will not have 0 or negative numbers in that column).

Answer (score 1):

Add all to values to an array, then [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it using `', '` as glue

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $result[] = $row['v2id'];
}
echo implode(', ', $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array(1,2,'Hello',3,4,'1,234.56');

$outstream = fopen("php://temp", 'r+');
fputcsv($outstream, $data, ',', '"');
rewind($outstream);
$csv = fgets($outstream);
fclose($outstream);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ids = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $ids[] = (int)$row['v2id'];
}

echo implode(", ", $values);
```

1ID 2ID 3ID 4ID 8 can be converted to int by (int)$row['v2id'] so $ids will contain int only.

Answer (score 0):

My way would be this

> ```
> $csv = '';
> while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
>    /* Note the '.=' - appends variable */
>    $csv .= "ID ".$row['v2id'];
>    $csv .= ','; // This is the bit I missed out
> }
> /* Remove the final trailing comma */
> $csv = substr($csv, 0, -1);
> echo $csv;
> ```

The gold star for spotting the 'deliberate' mistake goes to ssapkota

Comment: There is no `,` how can it be CSV?